# Wordpress Loop - Not returning projects in specific category

Tags: php, wordpress, divi

I am attempting to simply pull in all projects in a specific category (e.g. 'websites' or 'featured').

When using:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'     => 'project',
    'category_name'  => 'websites',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
);
```

Nothing is returned.

When using simply:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'     => 'project',
);
```

I do actually get posts (projects) returning, just not in the category I want.

Here is my full code:

```
function gmb_register_project_section () { 

$args = array(
    'post_type'     => 'project',
    'category_name'  => 'websites',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
);

$post_query = new WP_Query($args);

if ($post_query->have_posts()) :
$output = '<div class="gmb_custom-project-module">';

    while ($post_query->have_posts()) {
        $post_query->the_post();

        $output .= '<a href="'. get_permalink(). '"><article class="gmb_project-item" style="background: url(\''. get_the_post_thumbnail_url(). '\') no-repeat center center;"><div class="inner"><h2>'.
                get_the_title(). '</h2></div></article></a>';
    }

wp_reset_postdata();

$output .= '</div>';

endif;

return $output; }

add_shortcode('gmb_project_section', 'gmb_register_project_section');
```

I am using the Divi theme, with a code module which allows you to input short codes into.

Thanks in advance,
Ben

Comment: Your code is correct. Are you sure the **project** spelling and website **category slug** are correct?

Comment: I'm sure! :/ - thanks

Comment: Please add `'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,` to your `$arg` array and test again.

Comment: Still nothing! - thanks for the suggestion though :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this bro:

```
$args = array(
'post_type'     => 'project',
'posts_per_page' => 10,
'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'categories',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => 'websites',
                ),
            ),
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function gmb_register_project_section () { 

$args = array(
    'post_type'     => 'project',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
     'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'your_taxonomy_name',  //Add your post type's taxonomy name
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => 'websites',
            ),
        ),
);

$post_query = new WP_Query($args);

if ($post_query->have_posts()) :
$output = '<div class="gmb_custom-project-module">';

    while ($post_query->have_posts()) {
        $post_query->the_post();

        $output .= '<a href="'. get_permalink(). '"><article class="gmb_project-item" style="background: url(\''. get_the_post_thumbnail_url(). '\') no-repeat center center;"><div class="inner"><h2>'.
                get_the_title(). '</h2></div></article></a>';
    }

wp_reset_postdata();

$output .= '</div>';

endif;

return $output; }

add_shortcode('gmb_project_section', 'gmb_register_project_section');
```